# N level category traversal in codeigniter view page

Tags: codeigniter, treeview

There is many example n level tree create and tree traversal but i could not understand how do i traverse the tree in codeigniter view page with out calling recursive function.I think it is not best practice to call recursive function in view page.So then how do traverse the multidimensional array for create dropdown.

This is my code in view page.how do i improve it

> value="0">Root Level
>
> $html .= ''.$valArr['category'].'';
>   if(array_key_exists('children', $valArr)){    $html .=
>   generateCategoryList($valArr['children']); }   } return $html; } ?>

Comment: i advise doing it on your `model`.

Comment: Then i have to write html like <select>  or ul  in model

Comment: No need , you can use the `form_dropdown` helper so from the model what you need is the proper structure which is key is the value, and value which is the label of the select